# How to get the PDF of a hard-to-find paper?

Tags: google-scholar

I'm finding this paper: *Adobe Camera Model*.

It's the second result in Google Scholar:
[the result of Google Scholar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2tIm.png)

That's it, without any linkings.

And I searched *Tech. rep., Adobe*, *Adobe Technical Reports* in Google, but get nothing useful.

I also tried the names of the authors.

What are the common methods to find the PDFs of such papers?

Comment: Is [this](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/lensprofile_creator/lensprofile_creator_cameramodel.pdf) it? It is the first result from Google...

Comment: Google Scholar results will vary depending on your past research (or so I've heard...), thus the inconsistencies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a relevant question

Comment: @101010111100 Yes, to me, looks like this is it

Comment: @101010111100 I'm surprised the Macromedia domain is still in use given how long ago they were absorbed by Adobe (and, for that matter, that Adobe still posts stuff on it).

Comment: @101010111100 Things are different to me. Sigh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that quite a few people have cited the work. The authors of those papers can be contacted for help. I'm hopeful that they will respond kindly.

I've experienced this before. Don't hesitate to ask them by email. But also, be ready to explain why it is needed and what you've tried to find it yourself. All the best!

Edit: The link by user 101010111100 looks like it!